# I would like to repeat all lines in a text file, depending the input value

Tags: c++, unix, sed

I would like to repeat all lines in a text file, depending the input value.
e.g.
before:

```
line1
line2
```

How many times would you like to repeat the line? 4
After:

```
line1
line1
line1
line1
line2
line2
line2
line2
```

I do not want to change the original file.

Maybe the sed command?

```
sed 'p;p;p' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

This would repeat all lines 3 times, but how can I ask a question instead to choose the repeat count?

I will use this from a c++ tool which has access to unix commands, can it be done with something like this? But how to get the variable value into to c++ system function? ->

```
cout << How many times would you like to repeat the line?;
cin >> variable;
system("sed 'variable' < infile.txt > outfile.txt");
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not do it all in C++??

Comment: your question basically boils down to "How to concatenate strings?", right? that would be `std::string("sed") + variable + ...` (assuming `variable` is a `string`)

Comment: @user463035818 I think OP wants to know if there is way to use numeric value in sed to specify repeat count.. answer would be no.. although, one could always write a logic to simulate it as sed is turing complete... better choice would be to use awk/perl... also, I don't get the downvotes.. at least leave a reason for that....

Comment: @Sundeep I didnt downvote, though questions along the line of "Can it be done like this: .... ?" tend to be misunderstood as "no effort", another factor might be that there is an (obvious?) easier way to get the same outcome and its not clear from the question why OP wants to use a system call

Comment: @user463035818 yeah good points.. which can be asked like you mentioned in comments.. allow OP to respond to that.. vote to close the question if needed.. but leaving reasons for downvote would help..

Comment: I tried this, but do not work: int main() { std::string var; cout << "enter number of p (e.g. p;p;p) to repeat line: "; cin >> var; system("sed " +var+ "< infile.txt > outfile.txt"); return 0; }

Comment: I trying to learn how to interact with linux from a c++ program.

Comment: @Sundeep not trying to have an argument here, but the first comment is asking for clarification and there was no reply until now. @ Joe in that case it would help if you add that information to your question. Whenever someone wants to do something in a non-obvious way with non-obvious constraints it is better to make them explicit in the question, this helps to avoid snarky comments and downvotes

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, although ugly, it works. Thank you for your help.

```
func() {
    std::string var;
    std::string tmp;
    int value;
    cout << "enter a number to repeat line: ";
    cin >> value;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++){
        oss << "p;";
        tmp = oss.str();
    }
    var = "sed " + tmp + " < infile.txt > outfile.txt"; 
    system(var.c_str());    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone knows how to skip repeat the first line when using sed? 
sed 'p;p;p' < infile.txt > outfile.txt

I know I can remove the lines afterwards:
sed '1,3 d' outfile.txt 

But how can I do it with one sed command?

eg.

before:
a
b
c
after:
b
b
b
c
c
c

Answer (score -2):

Did You try to Concatenate

```
system("sed "+variable+" < infile.txt > outfile.txt");
```